# How can I create 1 row based on the the timestamp in the first column of this data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qEm7.png)
I would like to collapse the rows so each timestamp is 1 row.

```
library(tidyverse)

table1 <- tribble(
  ~time, ~buoy, ~depth1, ~depth2, ~depth3,
  "t1",  "b1",  NA,     NA,     "value",
  "t1",  "b1",  NA,     "value", NA,
  "t1",  "b1",  "value", NA,     NA,
  "t2",  "b1",  NA,     NA,     "value",
  "t2",  "b1",  NA,     "value", NA,
  "t2",  "b1",  "value", NA,     NA
)
```

I currently have code to convert a long dataset with multiple parameters into a wide dataset with the timestamps as headers (see Table 2). I need the depths as headers and the time as rows in long format.

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTiL6.png)

```
table2 <- tribble(
  ~depth, ~buoy, ~time1, ~time2, ~timen, ...,
  "d1",   "b1",  "value", "value", "value", "v",
  "d2",   "b1",  "value", "value", "value", "v",
  "d3",   "b1",  "value", "value", "value", "v",
  "d4",   "b1",  "value", "value", "value", "v",
  "d2",   "b1",  "value", "value", "value", "v",
  "t2",   "b1",  "value", "value", "value", "v"
)
```

Comment: please share your data and expected output

Comment: Can you provide some representative data?  Using that data, what should your desired output look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jade Hinson! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a great start here), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.